# Tagfield is not working after applying emptyText

Tags: javascript, extjs, tags, extjs6

In my Programm I am using Tagfield and so Iam using `Ext.form.field.Tag`

```
requires: [
        'Ext.grid.filters.Filters',
        'Ext.form.field.Tag'
    ],
```

Later In code I ausing tagfield.

code is:

> ```
>  { 
>     xtype: 'tagfield', 
>     emptyText : "Hello", 
>     growMax  : 10,
> matchFieldWidth : false,
> valueField: 'title',
> displayField:'title',
> createNewOnBlur:true, 
> parentGrid : me, 
> editable : true,
> filterPickList: true,
> dataIndex:header.getAttribute("DATAINDEX"),
> queryMode: 'local', 
> disabled: true,
>      }
> ```

```
   Note : STore is loading from some other method and everything is working fine if I remove emptyText
```

After that everything is working fine, but when I am using `emptyText : "Hello"` or giving value to emptyText, emptyText is appearing but combo is working. Can not select value from combo. I tried to make fiddler but In all fiddler combo is coming after applying emptyText.

Am I missng anything ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead of emptyText in your tagField.

```
listeners:{
              afterrender:function(combo){
                  var me = this,
                  values = me.getValueRecords();
                  me.inputEl.set( {
                  'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Hello'});
              },
              change:function(tag){
                    var me = this,
                  values = me.getValueRecords();
                  me.inputEl.set( {
                  'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Hello'});
              }
         }
```

Comment: Can you explain me what your are doing.

Comment: Thanks It works. I want to know what is the error. This is one of way to achive this but its good to know where it getting mistakes.

Comment: I am just creating a placeholder for tag field instead of emptyText. Afterrender just check length, if it is true then set a text in tagfield inputEl.

Comment: There are lots of problems in Extjs js tag field with emptyText as compare to comboBox with emptyText.

Like tabbing also not working when you use emptyText in tagfield.

This is alternate way for displaying emptyText in tag field.

Comment: Placeholder is not working in Internet explorer. IS there any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Add Listeners to solve this issue:

```
listeners: {
              afterrender: function (ctl, e, eOpts) {
                var values = ctl.getValueRecords();
                ctl.inputEl.set( { 'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Your text'});  
              },
              change:function(ctl){
                var values = ctl.getValueRecords();
                ctl.inputEl.set( { 'placeholder': values.length ? '' :'Your text'});
              }
}
```

Comment: Thanks This is bit old question but many thanks to answer. I will check and revert back to you.